# Unknown type name in C header file

Tags: c, struct, header, include, declaration

I'm facing an issue when I compile my project. I'm trying to put in a queue a struct which I've decalred in a header file like this:

**Appointment functions header file** ("signupFunctions.h" is where I've my "Patient" declaration):

```
#ifndef appointmentFunctions_H__
#define appointmentFunctions_H__

#include "queueFunctions.h"
#include "signupFunctions.h"

typedef struct{
    int cough;
    int rDistress;
    int fatigue;
    int fever;
}symptoms;

typedef symptoms *Symptoms;

typedef struct {
    Patient patient;
    Symptoms symptoms;
    int day;
    int mon;
    int year;
    int flag;
}appointment;

typedef appointment *Appointment;

int getSymptomsValue(Appointment A);
void setSymptoms(Appointment A);
void requestAppointment(Patient P, qNodePtr *head, qNodePtr *tail);

#endif
```

**Queue functions header file**:

```
#ifndef queueFunctions_H__
#define queueFunctions_H__

#include "appointmentFunctions.h"

typedef struct qNode{
    Appointment A;
    struct qNode *next;
}QueueNode;

typedef QueueNode *qNodePtr;

void printQueue(qNodePtr currentPtr);
int isEmpty(qNodePtr head);
void dequeue(qNodePtr *head, qNodePtr *tail);
void enqueue(qNodePtr *head, qNodePtr *tail, Appointment App);

#endif
```

Once I compile I get:

```
In file included from appointmentFunctions.h:4:0,
                 from menuFunctions.h:5,
                 from main.c:4:
queueFunctions.h:7:2: error: unknown type name 'Appointment'
  Appointment A;
  ^~~~~~~~~~~
queueFunctions.h:16:46: error: unknown type name 'Appointment'
 void enqueue(qNodePtr *head, qNodePtr *tail, Appointment App);
                                              ^~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from appointmentFunctions.h:4:0,
                 from menuFunctions.h:5,
                 from signupFunctions.c:5:
queueFunctions.h:7:2: error: unknown type name 'Appointment'
  Appointment A;
  ^~~~~~~~~~~
queueFunctions.h:16:46: error: unknown type name 'Appointment'
 void enqueue(qNodePtr *head, qNodePtr *tail, Appointment App);
                                          ^~~~~~~~~~~
```

..and so on. What's the problem? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In appointmentFunctions.h you include queueFunctions.h

So when queueFunctions.h is read the type `Appointment` is unknown.

It doesn't help you that queueFunctions.h also includes appointmentFunctions.h because at that time appointmentFunctions_H__ is already defined, i.e. the file content will not be read.

If file X.h depends on something from file Y.h and at the same time Y.h depends on something from file X.h you have a design error that must be fixed.

As far as I can see the dependency is only **pointer to struct** so you can get rid of the dependency by forward declaring the struct.

In queueFunctions.h do these changes:

```
#include "appointmentFunctions.h" --> struct appointment;

Appointment --> struct appointment*
```

BTW: It's opinion based but most programmers avoid typedef's for pointers. If it's done it's typically a good idea to use a name that clearly tells that this is a pointer, i.e. something like:

```
typedef appointment *Appointment; --> typedef appointment *appointmentPtr;
```

Answer (score 1):

You recursively included one header in another

```
#ifndef appointmentFunctions_H__
#define appointmentFunctions_H__

#include "queueFunctions.h"
#include "signupFunctions.h"
//...
```

and

```
#ifndef queueFunctions_H__
#define queueFunctions_H__

#include "appointmentFunctions.h"
//...
```

So the compiler issues an error.

You shall not do that.

That is the header `appointmentFunctions.h` at once includes the header `queueFunctions.h` in which there is declaration

```
typedef struct qNode{
    Appointment A;
    struct qNode *next;
}QueueNode;
```

but the declaration of `Appointment` is not visible yet. It follows after the inclusion of the header `queueFunctions.h`.